# How to change Eclipse error dialog style?

Tags: eclipse, styling

It's obvious I don't even know how to call that dialog. Surley it's not AutoComplete dialog, but following screen shows element I want to know how to style:

[image]

It's on Windows 7, I want to change background and link color as well as their corresponding settings on mouse hover.

Comment: Which OS are you using?Update the post and explain the what kind of style you are expecting i.e do you want to change the link colour, dialog background color etc etc.

Comment: Windows 7, background and link color + their hovers (question updated)